Need validation for my IR tracking device part list
I have a side project where I want to build something like that and it has been a very long time since I have done electronic. So I need some "validation".
The project is to build an IR tracking device for flight simulation game. For that, I need to power 3 IR LED from my USB port (from my computer mother board), and used an old PlayStation camera for the receiver.
I already have the camera. And I live in France, so I plan to shop the component via this site (or another one if you know a better one haha ^^).
I found an old tutorial about that project right here but the SFH485P led is not available in my country shop anymore.
The schematic is:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So with the help of this website for the resistor, I managed to list the following component:

USB cable: https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/909-USB-SERIAL-CABLE
the IR LED: https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/720-SFH4547
the fuse: https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/652-MFR025
the resistor: https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/SEI-Stackpole/RNF18FTD5R10?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlubZbdhIBIAPvukx9%2FY0xZMXUz0zjqWA%3D

Do I have chosen the right part and is the IR angle ok for my use case?
The resistor have a very long delay to be shipped, so if you have any idea for using another one / another IR LED tell me :)

probably the wrong resistor, it's only 1/8th watt. What's your expected resistor dissipation? Then it's a good idea to get a resistor rated at 2x that power.

Hey, I don't understand the question "What's your expected resistor dissipation?" ^^
I estimate the 1/8th watt via this website https://ledcalculator.net/?mode=wiring#p=5&v=1.5&c=100&n=3&o=s

I plan to use the resistor on a printed support via a 3d printer, but I have no idea what value is good for this kind of use for dissipation.

I found a 5v 5.1Ohms resistor in 5W, is this ok ? https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/CW0055R100JB12?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvNd0dY0KymzmzFoYHC323BeaNmzUC5H7I%3D

Your link above gives the power dissipation for the resistor (51 milliwatts), so 1/8W is ok.  However, 1/4W resistors are barely any different in size or cost, and your circuit will be very sensitive to the exact forward voltages of the LEDs and the supply voltage, so might not be a bad idea to use 1/4W just to be very safe.

The SFH4547 LED you've selected seems to be a suitable replacement for the SFH485P mentioned in the tutorial. It has similar specifications and should work well for your project. However, it's essential to verify if its viewing angle meets your requirements for tracking in your flight simulation game.
